# How to inject one controller function to another controller using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two ng-controllers for example controller1, controller2, i want to inject controller2 method in controller1 and i want to access through my JS API function using "document.querySelector('[ng-controller=custom-entity-design-ctrl]')". 
  Is it possible to get? I tried using factory services that also not working. It's saying error $scope not defined.

**source code**

```
**controller1**
  myApp.controller("controller1",function($scope, $document, $http, $localStorage) {
        $scope.test1 = function() {
              alert("test1");
         };
  });

  **controller2**
  myApp.controller("controller2",function($scope,$http,$compile,$localStorage, $log) {
        $scope.test2 = function() {
              alert("test2");
         };
  });
```

In detail... i want to access $scope.test2 method from controller1.

I tried using factory also not working.

**source code:**

```
  myApp.factory("testService", function($compile, $http, $scope) {     
   $scope.test2 = function() {
              alert("test2");
         };   
   }

   factory injected in controller1

   myApp.controller("controller1",['testService',function($scope, $document, $http, $localStorage) {
        $scope.test1 = function() {
              alert("test1");
         };
  }]);
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Comment: you cant inject a controller in to another, please have a look at services.

Comment: Use a factory or service

Comment: @pixelbits . i tried using factory it is not working. please have a look my fiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/bagya1985/4o7rcj4y/

Comment: You must use Service, not Factory. Service, we use where we need to share data among controllers. Factory, we use where we need to create different-2 instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were at the right path with use of `.factory()`:

```
myApp.factory("testService", function($compile, $http, $scope) {     
   // just return the things in an object.
   return {
      name:"angular js",
      test2 : function(){ alert("test2") }
   }  
});

myApp.controller("controller1",['$scope', '$document', '$http', '$localStorage','testService', function($scope, $document, $http, $localStorage, testService) {
    $scope.test1 = function() {
        alert("test1");
        testService.test2(); // use the method from the testService.
    };
}]);
```

You were missing the service in the function args of the controller and when you use `.factory()` service then make sure to return everything in an object `{}`, with this object you can provide multiple values/methods etc.

[Check the plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/WQihzQyCrCjrjhGtgvKb?p=preview)